# Problem booting into Windows 8.1 after using Ubuntu live cd 12.04

Tags: boot, windows

I have a Lenovo laptop tha came with Windows 8 64bit pre-installed.

I recently decided to pop in an Ubuntu Live CD 12.04 and I was messing around with it and I decided to try to erase the Windows password using the command that I found in  [this website](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14369/change-or-reset-windows-password-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd).

The first time I tried this command, I was able to restart and boot into my Windows 8 and the second time as well (I kept doing this command because it didn't seem to work so I thought a 3rd will be a charm and well...) and the third time I did it I don't know what I did wrong, it seemed like I did everything the same, but the next time I tried to boot up it just said "checking media" and it keeps restarting.

So when I boot into the Ubuntu live CD, I can see my Windows 8 hard drive and the Windows recovery partition when I click the home folder.

I would just reinstall my Windows 8, but I need the product key which I never wrote down and it's not under the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The same website offers a solution on [how to recover Windows product key](http://www.howtogeek.com/64600/how-to-recover-windows-and-software-keys-from-a-broken-computer/) (and other Microsoft software) using a Linux live CD/USB. You need to have a separate storage to copy the

> C:\Windows\system32\config

directory to run the recovery software.

Once you have the product key, write it down and keep it somewhere safe.